# Member for 2 years but posted in 2011

Tags: support, community-user, mso-mse-split

Is this a bug? I just visited the profile of the Community user and found this.
Check the marked area.

[image]

Comment: Obviously, he simply took a 5 years *sabbatical*.

Comment: Clearly, we are dealing with a Time Lord.

Comment: @JustinTime - Surely that should be "**another** Time Lord"!  Aren't you one as well?

Comment: So when one of my posts is updated by Community, I am actually being corrected by a *5* year old, not a 2 year old. Not sure that makes me feel much better ...

Comment: @Leigh I, for one, welcome our new background process overlords.

Comment: @AdamLear - Benevolent overlords.  That is how it all starts ... ;-)

Comment: he probably became a manager.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (MSE) used to be called Meta Stack Overflow but still acted as a network-wide meta site. Some time ago we moved it to its current location. I'll leave "exactly when did this happen" as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) as you see it now was created as a brand new site at that point, so the Community user's "age" matches that date. A number of questions were migrated back to MSO from MSE since they were specific to the Stack Overflow community and they predate the creation of MSO as you see it now. That's why some questions were seemingly posted before the Community user profile was created.

Comment: But in profile of people, it shows the original duration. eg . in your profile, it shows `Member for 7 years, 9 months` . How it happens?

Comment: @SagarV For actual users, the creation date on a meta site is inherited from the parent main site (in this case, Stack Overflow). Community is a special fake account that isn't linked the same way people-owned accounts are.

Comment: Basically, when someone joins Stack Overflow, they don't have a meta profile created at the same time. If they end up going to Meta Stack Overflow while logged in, a profile will be quietly created for them with all profile fields, creation date, etc. copied from the SO profile. Community user, on the other hand, is simply created when the database is set up, with hardcoded profile fields and a creation date that matches the DB setup time.

Comment: @SagarV do know that it is not that uncommon to have posts owned by users that are created before the current user account was created. I believe account merges are the root cause for this. See [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/633920) to get a list of those accounts.

Comment: @rene why merging accounts didn't show the date of which the first account was created?

Comment: @SagarV that depends I think which account is chosen as the account to keep but only Adam, as head of account merges, can confirm.

Comment: @SagarV The direction of the merge is based on the network account id, not site user id. So, let's say someone has two accounts X and Y. X was created 3 years ago, but the user didn't join Stack Overflow until 1 month ago. Account Y was created by mistake two years ago and the user joined Stack Overflow right away. When X and Y are merged, X-the-account has a lower id, so it's preserved as the primary account. Content from profiles on Y is attached to it, but the age of the SO profile is still just 1 month since that's what it was on X.

Comment: @rene I'd need hazard pay to be the "head of account merges" ;) But either way, see the merge explanation in my comment above.